# How to set a value from TextBox to CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetContents() {
       var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
       document.getElementById('field').value = oEditor.getData();
    }
</script>
```

Here i passed value from CKEditor to text field. In the similar way I want do vice verse from textbox to CKEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
field.value = oEditor.getValue();
oEditor.setValue(field.value);
```

But why do you need to do it? CKEditor perfectly works in form as it is when you apply it to the textarea.

Also as your function named `GetContents` it should return a value but not set it to the textbox. Follow the coding guidelines.

Comment: i want to set value to the ckeditor via taxtbox r some oter control

Comment: oEditor is the value which i get from ckEditor.i want to take the value text box and put it in the ckeditor

Comment: yes, I posted the example. use `setValue` method of the editor

Comment: k sir i ill try with it

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

     function GetContents() {
         var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
         alert(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').value);
         oEditor.setData(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>').value);
     }
    </script>



I created the instance and did its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `<textarea>` value with editor's data, use [CKEDITOR.editor.updateElement](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement).

If you want to synchronize editor's data with `<textarea>`, use [CKEDITOR.editor.setData](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData). There's no method in the API similar to `updateElement` that works the opposite way. Still, the official [jQuery Adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery-section-3) allows setting editor's data by calling `$( textarea ).val( newValue )`.

Answer (score 0):

function GetContents() {
         var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
         alert(document.getElementById('').value);
         oEditor.setData(document.getElementById('').value);
     }

I created the instance and did its working fine.